# python regex where a set of options can occur at most once in a list, in any order

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm wondering if there's any way in python or perl to build a regex where you can define a set of options can appear at most once in any order.   So for example I would like a derivative of `foo(?: [abc])*`, where `a`, `b`, `c` could only appear once.   So:

```
foo a b c
foo b c a
foo a b
foo b
```

would all be valid, but

```
foo b b
```

would not be

Comment: Is each of the four lines you give a string, and if so, what do you mean they all "would be valid"? "Valid" in relation to what? Is there an unstated string you are referring to by "valid"?

Comment: These would be strings that would match the regex

Comment: I feel like string methods would be faster then regex in this case. I would suggest something like `words = string.split(); len(words) == len(set(words))` to check if there are only unique values in the config.

Comment: For such a regular expression you would need to list all combinations, since regex don't have memory. There are options to build in a memory (for example capture groups) in those languages, but then it is, strictly speaking, not an regex.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use regex for this? It can be done in 2 lines or so using a `set`, while maintaining legibility and likely speed. What is the advantage of using regex, except as an abstract challenge (which is a worthy purpose in and of itself)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist:  Basically, I need to create a table of CLI's that effect various entries in a database.  Regex's seemed convenient as I can represent some very complicated syntax.   I'm not familiar with how I would use `set` for this

Comment: `s = mystring.split(); if s[0] == 'foo' and len(set(s[1:])) == len(s) - 1 and all(x in ['a', 'b', 'c' for x in s[1:]]): print('OK')`

Comment: @Mad guy, as you may have noticed, the motivation for many regex questions is to better understand how regular expressions work, not whether the use of a regex is the best approach for the problem at hand. That's certainly fair game. In my experience it hardly ever makes sense to use a highly complex regex, if for no other reason that it is too hard to properly test it, but striving to understand the toughies makes for a better understanding of the more pedestrian ones.

Comment: @CarySwoveland. That's a really nice summary. I tried to capture it with my comment (the part about "...an abstract challenge (which is a worthy purpose in and of itself)"), but I really like how you phrased that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group and a negative lookahead:

For `Perl`, you can use this variant with [forward referencing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html):

```sh
^foo((?!.*\1) [abc])+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P9Qp9r/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `foo`: Match `foo`
- `(`: Start a capture group #1

  - `(?!.*\1)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't match what we have in capture group #1 anywhere in input
  - `[abc]`: Match a space followed by `a` or `b` or `c`
- `)+`: End capture group #1. Repeat this group 1+ times
- `$`: End

As mentioned earlier, this regex is using a feature called **Forward Referencing** which is a back-reference to a group that **appears later in the regex pattern**.  JGsoft, .NET, Java, Perl, PCRE, PHP, Delphi, and Ruby allow forward references but Python doesn't.

---

Here is a **work-around of same regex for Python** that doesn't use forward referencing:

```sh
^foo(?!.* ([abc]).*\1)(?: [abc])+$
```

Here we use a negative lookahead before repeated group to check and fail the match if there is any repeat of allowed substrings i.e. `[abc]`.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/P9Qp9r/3)

Comment: Just a quick note to any future readers referencing this; this solution does have a limitation -- while it works for the posted question, if you wanted to expand your pattern to be `foo((?!.*\1) [abc])+ bar((?!.*\1) [abc])+` this would prevent a match for `foo a bar a`.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry: It would be `^foo((?!.*\1) [abc])+ bar((?!.*\2) [abc])+$` because we have to use `\2` for the 2nd capture group.

Comment: Ahh yes, my bad!  (sorry, my issue was with this, but also `foo b bar b` still doesn't work because `bar` starts with ` b`, which the regex picks up, but this is handled easily with a word boundary...

Comment: Yes `^foo((?!.*\1\b) [abc])+ bar((?!.*\2\b) [abc])+$` might be the one

Comment: Actually, even with this, I'm getting some weird results.  According to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Kg2xGj/1), `^foo((?!.*\1\b) [abc])* bar((?!.*\2\b) [abc])*$` matches `foo a bar a`, and `foo a b c bar`, but does not match `foo a b c bar a` ... (note chaged `+` to `*` from your regex)

Comment: But the same pattern works on a live system runnng perl 5.16.3...

Answer (score 6):

You can assert that there is no match for a second match for a space and a letter at the right:

```
foo(?!(?: [abc])*( [abc])(?: [abc])*\1)(?: [abc])*
```

- `foo` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?: [abc])*` Match optional repetitions of a space and a b or c
  - `( [abc])` Capture group, use to compare with a backreference for the same
  - `(?: [abc])*` Match again a space and either a b or c
  - `\1` Backreference to group 1
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?: [abc])*` Match optional repetitions or a space and either a b or c

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E778Ef/1)

If you don't want to match only foo, you can change the quantifier to 1 or more `(?: [abc])+`

---

A variant in perl reusing the first subpattern using `(?1)` which refers to the capture group `([abc])`

```
^foo ([abc])(?: (?!\1)((?1))(?: (?!\1|\2)(?1))?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pkLEn9/1)

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't have to be a regex:

```py
import collections

# python >=3.10
def is_a_match(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return (
      (len(words) > 0)
      and (words[0] == 'foo')
      and (collections.Counter(words) <= collections.Counter(['foo', 'a', 'b', 'c']))
    )

# python <3.10
def is_a_match(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return (
      (len(words) > 0)
      and (words[0] == 'foo')
      and not (collections.Counter(words) - collections.Counter(['foo', 'a', 'b', 'c']))
    )

# TESTING
#foo a b c True
#foo b c a True
#foo a b True
#foo b True
#foo b b False
```

Or with a set and the walrus operator:

```py
def is_a_match(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return (
      (len(words) > 0)
      and (words[0] == 'foo')
      and (
        (s := set(words[1:])) <= set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        and len(s) == len(words) - 1
      )
    )
```

Comment: Or you could use a set. It adds one extra check, but you don't have to keep track of the values: `(s := set(words[1:])) <= set(['a', 'b', 'c']) and len(s) == len(words) - 1`

Comment: You don't need the extra parentheses. `and` can be chained indefinitely as-is. Evaluation is guaranteed left-to-right since it's a short-circuiting operator.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, I need them if I want to keep the indentation this way ;)

Comment: I meant just the ones around the bit I suggested. Those two checks can keep the indentation of the return value without going further in.

Comment: Also, you don't really need the walrus: just initialize `s` right before the `return`. If you do use the walrus, you can define `words` inline as well in the check for `len(words := ...) > 0`.

Comment: I don't mind computing `words` before the `return`, because `words` needs to be computed no matter what. However, I don't want to compute `d` unless it needs to be computed. Or maybe I could change it this way: `return sentence[:3] == 'foo' and (s := set((words = sentence.split())[1:])) <= set(['a', 'b', 'c']) and len(s) == len(words) - 1`

Comment: I'm thinking that might pass `food a b c`

Comment: On a side note, I would make `set(['a', 'b', 'c'])` into a global constant rather than recomputing it every time

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using references to previously captured groups.

```regex
foo(?: ([abc]))?(?: (?!\1)([abc]))?(?: (?!\1|\2)([abc]))?$
```

This gets quite long with many options. Such a regex can be generated dynamically, if necessary.

```py
def match_sequence_without_repeats(options, seperator):
    def prevent_previous(n):
        if n == 0:
            return ""
        groups = "".join(rf"\{i}" for i in range(1, n + 1))
        return f"(?!{groups})"

    return "".join(
        f"(?:{seperator}{prevent_previous(i)}([{options}]))?"
        for i in range(len(options))
    )


print(f"foo{match_sequence_without_repeats('abc', ' ')}$")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified version of anubhava's answer, using a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) (which works in Python, and is easier to understand at least for me) instead of a forward reference.

Match using  `[abc]` inside a capturing group, then check that the text matched by the capturing group does not appear again anywhere after it:

```
^foo(?:( [abc])(?!.*\1))+$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/otEzZP/1)

- `^`: Start
- `foo`: Match `foo`
- `(?:`: Start non-capturing group `(?:( [abc])(?!.*\1))`

  - `( [abc])`: Capturing Group 1, matching a space   followed by either `a`, `b`, or `c`
  - `(?!.*\1)`: Negative lookahead, failing to match if the text matched by the first capturing group occurs after zero or more characters matched by `.`
- `)+`: End non-capturing group and match it 1 or more times
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

I have assumed that the elements of the string can be in any order and appear any number of times. For example, `'a foo'` should match and `'a foo b foo'` should not.

You can do that with a series of alternations employing lookaheads, one for each substring of interest, but it becomes a bit of a dog's breakfast when there are many strings to consider. Let's suppose you wanted to match zero or one `"foo"`'s and/or zero or one `"a"`'s. You could use the following regular expression:

```
^(?:(?!.*\bfoo\b)|(?=(?:(?!\bfoo\b).)*\bfoo\b(?!(.*\bfoo\b))))(?:(?!.*\ba\b)|(?=(?:(?!\ba\b).)*\ba\b(?!(.*\ba\b))))
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/sOBFj4/1)

This matches, for example, `'foofoo'`, `'aa'` and `afooa`. If they are not to be matched remove the word breaks (`\b`).

Notice that this expression begins by asserting the start of the string (`^`) followed by two positive lookaheads, one for `'foo'` and one for `'a'`. To also check for, say, `'c'` one would tack on

```
(?:(?!.*\bc\b)|(?=(?:(?!\bc\b).)*\bc\b(?!(.*\bc\b))))
```

which is the same as

```
(?:(?!.*\ba\b)|(?=(?:(?!\ba\b).)*\ba\b(?!(.*\ba\b))))
```

with `\ba\b` changed to `\bc\b`.

It would be nice to be able to use back-references but I don't see how that could be done.

By hovering over the regular expression in the link an explanation is provided for each element of the expression. (If this is not clear I am referring to the cursor.)

Note that

```
(?!\bfoo\b).
```

matches a character provided it does not begin the word `'foo'`. Therefore

```
(?:(?!\bfoo\b).)*
```

matches a substring that does not contain `'foo'` and does not end with `'f'` followed by `'oo'`.

Would I advocate this approach in practice, as opposed to using simple string methods? Let me ponder that.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the strings doesn't matter, and you want to make sure every string occurs only once, you can turn the list into a set in Python:

```
my_lst = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
my_set = set(lst)

print(my_set)
# {'a', 'c', 'b'}
```

Comment: That will not match `foo`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Citation for Python's built-in sets? Erm okay.

Comment: @marcelm I think the point was: "add additional information as to how sets can help solve the original problem", since it's not clear how using `set( ... )` will help check that a string is a match or not.

Comment: @Stef Perhaps, and I agree the answer can be improved that way. But honestly, the comment reads like a canned message asking for links, which I don't think is appropriate.

Comment: @marcelm I think the answer is downright wrong, in the sense that it merely points out the existence of `set` without actually answering the question; and the bot's message was a polite "Your answer could be improved" rather than a more forward "You didn't actually answer the question"

Comment: Apologies @Stef I'm quite new here and was just trying to help. Was thinking that if the result he needs is a list where each item only occurs once, he could use set.  As someone else already pointed out, this was not the result that OP wanted. :)

Comment: @Sinceris Yes, what the OP wants is to test whether each item only occurs once or not; they don't need to produce a new list. But you could do something like `len(set(l)) == len(l)` to check whether all the elements in a list are unique.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to add to the above answers except here is a regex that does not use back or forward references. Instead it uses 3 separate negative lookahead assertions to ensure that the input does not contain 2 occurrences of either `a` or `b` or `c`. The regex also allows for liberal uses of spaces.

```
^foo(?![^a]*a[^a]*a)(?![^b]*b[^b]*b)(?![^c]*c[^c]*c)( +[abc])* *$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6UReEn/1/)

1. `^` - Matches start of string
2. `(?![^a]*a[^a]*a)` - Negative lookahead assertion that what follows does not contain two occurrences of `a`
3. `(?![^b]*b[^b]*b)` - Negative lookahead assertion that what follows does not contain two occurrences of `b`
4. `(?![^c]*c[^c]*c)` - Negative lookahead assertion that what follows does not contain two occurrences of `c`
5. `( +[abc])*` - Matches 0 or more occurrences of: 1 or more spaces followed by an `a` or `b` or `c`
6. `*` - Matches 0 or more occurrences of space
   7 `$` - Matches the end of the string

The regex looks "clunky" but is very straightforward. With input `foo a b c` the successful match is done in 35 steps and with input `foo b b` the unsuccessful match is done in 13 steps. Thich compares favorably with the other answers.